# Access read-only online SQLite from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, readonly

I want to develop an web application that can be served without web server. I mean, via file:///... in a web browser. The application will use HTML5 and Javascript. Also , I would like to add a SQLite with the data to be presented in the application. The database will be static so a read-only access is enough. I don't want a HTML5 local storage solution because the SQLite database is already created and must be load from "server".

I don't find any solution. A pseudocode example may be the following one:

```
var db = load ("file:///path/to/my/database/file.sqlite");

db.execute ("SELECT * FROM DATABASE");

// Show items
```

Comment: Don't do it. `file://` is a nightmare. Best bet is a couchapp. Convert your sqlite database into a couch database

Comment: Why don't you simply use AJAX ?

Comment: @DavidLaberge Because I don't have a web server.

Comment: @Raynos I heard about couch database but I don't know how it works, advantages and disadvantages. I will have a look. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Raynos Do I need to install some additional software to use a CouchApp? I would like to make a standalone application running on a web browser.

Comment: @Urizev a CouchApp is just a CouchDB server. You run couchDB. (there are plenty of hosted couchdb services out there). You would generally use node.js to make developing a couchApp easier. So you would install linux & node on your development machine.

Comment: @Raynos I cannot install additional software besides the browser and the HTML and SQLite files. I know it could be really weird but there are requirements imposed by client.

Comment: @Urizev overwrite your client. Tell your client you need a server. If he needs a good reason tell him how it increases productivity by a factor of 5 saving him costs. If he needs more reasons tell him that you need a server for security that's not a joke. There are plenty of free couchDB hosts. Use those.

Comment: @Raynos I would like to do this but sometimes the client requirements are stupid but immutable. Other times the client has good reasons for such requirements but also immutable.

Comment: "good reasons" === fallacy. Alternatively get _good_ clients

Answer (score 1):

load from the system files, I think this is not posible due to security reasons.

chek this online tool to manage local data storage at: http://wdbengine.sourceforge.net

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox 7. I am afraid that it is not possible to implement a portable solution for my problem.